# Bootstrap JS doesn't work on local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I shrink the page the navbar reduces in size appropriately, but the nav collapse button doesn't work. I can't see anything wrong with my code.

Why would this code work here or on JSFiddle, but not on a local machine using either IE or Chrome?

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93xaxorv/3/))

```html
<html>

<head runat="server">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>My Library <small>A library for people who like libraries.</small>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="navfluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationbar">
            <ul style="width: 100%" class="nav navbar-nav navigationList">
              <li id="homeListItem" class="active">
                <a href="home.aspx">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li id="libraryListItem">
                <a href="library.aspx">Library</a>
              </li>
              <li id="aboutUsListItem">
                <a href="aboutus.aspx">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li id="contactListItem">
                <a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li id="loginListItem">
                <a href="login.aspx">Login</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you check your network tab in the debugger to make sure your javascript is loading properly?

Comment: Maybe your bootstrap js file is not correct, copy and add this bootstrap file again: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a misspell of "scripts/boostrap.js" which should be "scripts/bootstrap.js".

Comment: Aww geez, someone kill me now.  Thanks.